# How to save previously searched results using Google Places Autocomplete API iOS

Tags: ios, autocomplete, google-places-api

After I implement, google Places API (for searching places in my Map), i would like to save the previously searched (searched and selected) place and show it the next time he taps on the search bar in the app.

Like the top 3 searches(History of previous searches). 
I am not able to do so because I make use of GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController as my default search results controller. Here is my code.

```
_resultsViewController = [[GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController alloc] init];
_resultsViewController.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_resultsViewController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = _resultsViewController;
```

According to Google Places API Documentation:https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete
How to update the tableview(resultsViewController) with the previously searched results

Comment: try to read whole documentation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  // Do something with the selected place.
  NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
  NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
  NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
}
```

Use this delegate method where you will get selected searched place and save this place name to your database ,squilite or at any best place where you want. And using your databse update your table.

Answer (score 0):

For having functionality that user can select the last selected Place. It would be nice if you can use database or save it in NSUserDefaults. And add a check in your tableview for fetching the user default, if found append it to the index 0 of the array.